# Generic way of handling exceptions in windows phone?

Tags: exceptions, windows-phone-7, exception-handling, error-handling

I mean what are some of the ways other programmers deal with exception for example, when an error occurs when accessing a web service for say. If an example cant be given for windows phone, give the closest you could.

Comment: don't bombard with questions. Take your time and take a look at all the links posted to you. Maybe after you read them you won't have so many question

Comment: Could you point me to right direction as I have not found the answer I was looking for?

Comment: I tryed my best with my previous answer. I'm not familiar with windows-phone programming, so I can't help you anything here. But from the speed that your questions come I see that you didn't even try to see what the previous answers were about. If you don't read the answers and the links, than what's the point of asking questions?

Comment: Could you just give me a genric answer then, one that does not apply to windows phone? Just looking for help thats all. And cheers  for even bothering to comment, I will look better next time.

Comment: There can be no trivial answers. I can only advise you to encapsulate exception-handling, and to find some good tutorial. unfortunately, I can't suggest any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways how to handle errors. basically you use framework to handle the application errors as well as there is a way to handle device related exceptions.

Here is a good intro to how to handle device specific exceptions on windows phone: - 
[Windows Phone 7 Development : Handling Device Exception](http://programming4.us/mobile/2056.aspx)

There is a related pots in SE - [Windows Phone 7 - Handle Error in Application_UnhandledException with WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6210952/1437962).

Nice video-tutorial from Channel 9 - [Code Cleanup, Exception Handling, and Preparing for the Marketplace](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Code-Cleanup-Exception-Handling-and-Preparing-for-the-Marketplace)